# How to set default color for excel cells in c#?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am trying out the below code but am getting some cells that are not changed to default cell color.

```
public static void xClearBackgorundColor(this Excel.Range r)
{
    r.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142;
}
```

Comment: Do the problem cells have conditional formatting applied?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the formatting first, like this:

```
public static void xClearBackgorundColor(this Excel.Range r)
{
    r.ClearFormats();
    r.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142;
}
```

or how about if you try to set it to `0`:

```
public static void xClearBackgorundColor(this Excel.Range r)
{
    r.Interior.ColorIndex = 0;
}
```

or even like this:

```
public static void xClearBackgorundColor(this Excel.Range r)
{
    r.Interior.Pattern = Excel.Constants.xlNone;
    r.Interior.TintAndShade = 0;
    r.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0;
}
```